# Get record count based on filtered view of entity list in Dynamics 365 Portal?

Tags: javascript, liquid, portal, dynamics-365

I am working on a new web page in Dynamics 365 Customer Self-Service Portal that will display an entity list of invoices with filtering enabled on the entity list.  One of the requirements is to display the number of invoices as well as a sum of all invoices in the current view.  I was able to get these values using some Liquid template code but I have noticed that the record count and sum do not refresh if I apply filters to the current view or if I change my view selection.  For example, I start with view Active Invoices, my Liquid code outputs the record count and sum to match, but then with the filtering options I narrow the list down to invoices created in the last week, the record count and sum do not refresh.  What's happening is the entity list refreshes without a page postback but the Liquid code will only execute with a page postback.  I've also considered using javascript to run another query based on the same view to get the record count and sum, but I see a couple problems with that: it's not ideal for performance as I would be querying the same data twice (once for entity list and once with javascript), and if a filter is applied to the entity list, I know I can attach javascript to a list refresh event, but can I access the filter options with javascript in order to get the correct query?  And of course, if I use Liquid code to get the values and do a page refresh then I lose my filters.  Is this even possible?

My current Liquid code on the page to get the record count and sum using the entity list associated with the page:

```
{% assign totalinvamt = 0.0 %}
{% entitylist id:page.adx_entitylist.id %}
    {% entityview %}
        Loaded default view of the entity list associated with the current page, with {{ entityview.total_records }} total records.
        {% for r in entityview.records %}
            {% assign totalinvamt = totalinvamt | plus: r["totalamount"] %}
        {% endfor %}
        <p>invoice total: {{ totalinvamt | format: "c" }}</p>
    {% endentityview %}
{% endentitylist %}
```